# Use a Self-Signed Certificate in production for a WCF service hosted in IIS?

Tags: wcf, security, certificate

I have a project consisting of a website (ASP.NET WebForms) and a desktop application (WinForms + WPF). Right now I'm designing a WCF Service to be hosted in IIS, that will be consumed by these applications. Service is authenticated by an Active Directory. Unfortunatelly in WCF all security related stuff needs a certificate to work.

On the development machine I know I can use a temporary certificate, but the problem is with production. The client server is accessible only from the intranet, so there is no SSL configured and no certificate (and it's not an option to buy one).

*My question is: can I use a IIS Self-Signed Certificate on production?* What are the disadventages of this? Until now I have used WCF only for simple AJAX calls, and haven't played with the security stuff and certificates.

Comment: self signed certificate will get you the same level of security as a certificate from any other vendor. it simply means that it is not be considered trusted by third parties.

Comment: I have found that to use a cert created by makecert only for testing purposes. Is an IIS Self-Signed Certificate the same as use an makecert?

Comment: Yes it is the same, but it is not trusted by third parties. The makecert also lets you attache a name to the certification where as the IIS7 does not. but in terms of security and key length they are the same